# Regular expression - match character, digits and special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string:

`test123 test ödo 123teö"st 123 m.1212 123t.est`

I only want to match strings as a whole that have either characters, digits and special character mixed together. So the regex should match the following string of the example above:

**test123** test ödo **123teö"st** 123 **m.1212**  **123t.est**

Could someone help me out please?

**Update**
Sorry for not giving a clear explanation of what I need.

1. I am using C#.
2. I need to find words that contain alphanumeric strings (eg abc123, 123abc, a1b2c3, 1abc23 etc). Also I need to find strings that contain any kind of symbols (symbols = anythings else than word characters and digits) (eg abc"123, "abc, ab?dd, 100mm", 345t{asd]dd)
3. If I find a match, I need to "tokenize" (separate digits, word characters and symbols with whitespace) these strings so `abc123` becomes `abc 123` or `345t{asd]dd` becomes `345 t { asd ] dd` etc

Comment: What the devil do you mean by “character” versus “special character”???  A code point is a code point is a code point.

Comment: @tchrist:  Read "character" as "letter" and "special character" as "punctuation".  It's very common usage among South Asian developers.

Comment: @Alan but that doesn't seem to match what the asker said. If "special character" is "punctuation", then "`123teö"st`" shouldn't match, but the asker says it does.

Comment: Presumably "special character" means "printable, non-alphanumeric, non-whitespace."  This is general programmer jargon (as in, *"password must contain at least one special character"*), not just specific to south-asian developers.

Comment: @BlueRaja: In my experience, Western programmers (or Americans, at least) use "punctuation" exactly the same way you're using "special character".  But I think both usages can be considered well established.

Comment: @BlueRaja: That's what I'm saying: we misuse the word "punctuation" to mean the same thing you mean by "special character": *printable, non-alphanumeric, non-whitespace*.

Comment: @Alan: If you use [unichars](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unichars) to run `unichars -c '\p{Diacritic}'` (which is a “derived” property), you’ll see that it includes code points from general categories `\p{Ll}`, `\p{Lm}`, `\p{Lo}`, `\p{Mc}`, `\p{Mn}`, `\p{Po}`, and `\p{Sk}`. 188 of them are `\p{Alphabetic}`, and 421 are not. So perhaps `[\pP\pS\pM\p{Diacritic}]` if you have full property support, or just skip the diacritic part if you do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using a regex flavor that supports lookaheads and Unicode properties, this should get you started:

```
(?!(?:\pL+|\pN+|\pP+)(?!\S))\S+
```

`\S+` matches one or more non-whitespace characters, but only after the negative lookahead asserts that those characters are not all letters (`\pL`), digits (`\pN`), or punctuation (`\pP`).  The *inner* negative lookahead--`(?!\S)`--ensures that the outer one examines *all* the characters in the word.

Although it might satisfy your requirements, this regex is really just a demonstration of the technique you'll probably want to use.  As it is, it can be fooled by "words" with (for example) control characters or dingbats in them.

Comment: I tend to find that people more often mean `[\pS\pP]` than just one or the other.

Comment: Good point.  Call that the Unicode category for "special character". ;)

Answer (score 0):

The  answer to the question you’ve actually asked is `(?s).+`, but perhaps you would care to refine your question.